# How to properly setup DNS for subdomain used only for sending

Tags: domain-name-system, email-bounces

I am using mailgun to sent our emails. It works fine in most of cases but recently I get bounced with: 
`450 4.1.8 Sender address rejected: Domain not found`

My setup is: xyz.com has mx setup for gmail.com
devmail.xyz.com is used in mailgun - only for sending emails

devmail.xyz.com has spf records set but it does not have any MX records or A records.

Should I set A records for devmail.xyz.com ? If so what ip address it should forward it to?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

450 The error-message from the remote SMTP-server is most likely because they are verifying that there is an MX or A record for the domain given in the **MAIL FROM: <>** SMTP command.

If your From-adress is something@devmail.xyz.com you should add an A or MX record for that, preferably pointing it to some server that accepts mail for that domain.

Comment: from address is something@xyz.com, but when I added A record for devmail.xyz.com it is working, but I do not like it because that A records pointing to the ip address that does not have anything to do with devmail.xyz.com -> there is no mail server for receiving mails (i do not receive emails for this subdomain at all)

Comment: Are you sure that both the from-adress in the email and the envelope-from (used in the SMTP MAIL FROM-command) are something@xyz.com? I am pretty sure you are using the @devmail adress.

Comment: not sure, mailgun shows in envelope: {sender: "something@xyz.com", ...} but what it sends in reality I do not know